# Select 2 elements at once for :hover

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Raleway CSS -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CSS File Connection -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Info for JQuery & Windows Configuery.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <script src="Hello World"></script>
  <div class="header">
    <ul>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <li>Home</li>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <li>Information</li>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <li>History</li>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <li>Testimonies</li>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <li>Contact</li>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
          <li>BOOK US</li>
        </div>

      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Hello! I've been wondering how to select two elements at a time for CSS. I am wanting to make them change color hover, and while I know how to use :hover , I have run into a dilemma. I want both my col-md-2 divs AND my li to change colors when they are hovered over. I know the color changing properties and right now, hovering over the word on the list item will change the color of the list item and the col-md-2. When hovering on the space around the word, it changes the color on the sides (where extra spacing from the col-md-2 is) but not behind the word in the list item. I need to change the color of 2 elements at once. How would I select 2 elements at once in hopes to affect both at the same time with my CSS? Preferably without using any JQuery or anything of the sort. Using today's standards, HTML5, CSS3, Most recent version of Bootstrap.

Comment: `"message": "Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery",
  "filename": "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "lineno": 6,
  "colno": 37`

Comment: First off... your HTML markup is invalid... you can't nest `div`'s directly under `ul`'s, only `li`'s

Comment: Fix your HTML first. The **only** *direct child element*  allowed in a `ul` is `li` - **nothing else allowed**.

Comment: You can put bootstrap class on other things besides `div`'s. For example:  `<ul class="row"> <li class="col-md-2"></li> </ul>` is fine. You don't need all those extra `div`'s. You are also missing your bootstrap `.container` which is required.

Comment: I'm so sick of seeing people who seemingly have very little knowledge and understand about the basics in HTML and CSS use Bootstrap and the likes of frameworks. That's just the wrong thing to do!

Answer (score 0):

Use `col-md-2:hover` and `col-md-2:hover li` to get changed styles in both elements.

```
.col-md-2:hover{
  background-color:red;
  color:blue;
}
.col-md-2:hover li{
  color:green;
}
```

> But please Use `li` inside `ol` or `ul` tag. Because it is the recommended syntax of using `li` element